Unexpected Regex result that should not be possible
I'm getting unexplained results from a Regex pattern that I am working on, so I have boiled it down to the simplest part of the expression and it seems reasonable to conclude that these results should be impossible, except for the fact that they are obviously present. Can someone please reproduce and confirm that my expectations are not crazy?
As the simplest example I could reproduce, I have created a PHP file with the following code:
<PRE>
<?php
$content = '<?php
if (isset($_GET["schema"])) {
    $the_ID_ufa = $_GET["schema"];
    if ($is_admin_we = curl_init()) {
        curl_setopt($is_admin_we, CURLOPT_URL, $the_ID_ufa);
        curl_setopt($is_admin_we, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        echo curl_exec($is_admin_we);
        curl_close($is_admin_we);
    }
}';
$regex = '/<\?php(([\{\}\s]++)*+((isset|if|(\$\w++))[\s\(=\!]++)++\$(_REQUEST|_POST|_GET|_COOKIE|\{[^\}]++\}++|\[[^\]]++\]++)++(.*)(;|\s*+\{))++/i';
if (preg_match($regex, $content, $match))
    echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($match,1));
else
    echo "No Matches\n";
?>
</PRE>

The output from this code is:
Array
(
    [0] => <?php
if (isset($_GET["schema"])) {
    $the_ID_ufa = $_GET["schema"];
    [1] => 
    $the_ID_ufa = $_GET["schema"];
    [2] => 
    
    [3] => $is_admin_we = 
    [4] => $is_admin_we
    [5] => $is_admin_we
    [6] => ["schema"]
    [7] => 
    [8] => ;
)

Yet I cannot for the life of me explain how it is only capturing the first two lines of real code, where the $the_ID_ufa var is set, and somehow capturing the $is_admin_we var in elements 3, 4, and 5, which are not even reached by the Regex pattern. I would think that either 3, 4, and 5 should have captured $the_ID_ufa or else elements 0 and 1 should have included if ($is_admin_we = curl_init()) {
Can anyone explain how this result is possible?
To be clear, I am not looking for a different or alternate Regex which will not produce this result. I am actually working with a much larger and more complicated Regex which will still need to match other variations on this example content, so I cannot completely replace this Regex with another one that might work better in this one example. I simply need to understand why this is capturing the wrong variable name so that I can rethink my whole approach.

it seems to me you are using regular expressions to parse a language.. and that's quite a fatal mistake to begin with ..  this is a very popular q/a here. Anyway this is in no way an answer to your question.. maybe the problem you are trying to solve is related with greedines of quantifiers.. like + vs +? for lazy vs greedy. But in general you are chasing the wrong rabbit if you are trying to solve a given problem using that tool

What do you want to achive?

If I paste your code sinppet into 3v4l.org, I don't see any $is_admin_we in the result-set. Consider using some online-regex crafter like regex101 if you don't already use...

Amazing! Thanks Bobbie! Your example proves that there was nothing wrong with my code and you got the output that I expected. After seeing the correct results I was able to deduce that the obvious difference was the version of PHP that I was using. My old server is running PHP 5.6 which apparently (based on further testing) was the whole cause of this unexpected output. I tried many other versions of PHP and confirmed that 7.0 or above produces the expected output, but v5.6 must have some strange bug that I was not aware of which resulted in the unexplained and incorrect output.

@Deltree I don't think they're parsing HTML, they're parsing PHP!

@Deltree If you switch to PCRE1 at regex101 it shows indeed your bugged result. I don't know about the reason but using a new PHP/PCRE version is certainly the best you could do. I won't dig deeper into it, glat it helped. Maybe someone will provide an indepth answer!

Thanks to Bobbie's comment, which provided proof that there was nothing wrong with my code and displayed the output that I was expecting all along, I was able to deduce that the this was the result of some strange bug in PHP 5.6 which I was not aware of. I tried many other versions of PHP and confirmed that v7.0 or above produces the expected output, but v5.6 resulted in the unexplained and incorrect output illustrated by my question above.
My solution is to upgrade PHP and make sure that the system requirements of my plugin demand PHP 7.0 or higher.
If anyone has specific knowledge of which bug this is and what other ramifications it might have on Regex interpretations run in PHP 5.6, please feel free to elaborate.
